# Learning how to parse basic json in to php echo of table

Tags: php, json

I know this has been done to death.
but i am really strugling
I have put together a webservice that generates a json,
i can and understand this bit in

```
// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://marcom.domain.com/corp/pub.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
```

this will dump out on the page [{"Torders":"3222","name":"john"},{"Torders":"579","name":"Kevin"}]
their is 5 in total but for this i am keeping it simple

I don't understand how to get these as an array so that my end result is a list
of name and Torders 
the rendered html would be something like this

```
<li>john 3222</li>
<li>Kevin 579 </li>
```

please don't send me to php manual page for json decode cause i am strugling to understand this.
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('http://marcom.domain.com/corp/pub.php');
$people = json_decode($json);
?>

<ul>
    <?php foreach ($people as $person): ?>
        <li><?=$person->name?> <?=$person->Torders?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

If you want to use curl, you'll want to set `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);` and get the return from `curl_exec()`

Answer (score 0):

U need to use json_decode()

```
$j = '[{"Torders":"3222","name":"john"},{"Torders":"579","name":"Kevin"}]';

$data = json_decode($j,true);
//print_r($data);

echo '<ul>';

foreach($data as $key=>$val){
  echo '<li>'.$val['name'].' '.$val['Torders'].'</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```